# Jquery Setting a boundary so animation does not leave screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple game where I have an animated image flying around the screen that you click to score points. After about 5 seconds the image will fly off the screen. I just want to contain it to a div by whatever means necessary.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#cursor').animate({
    top: '500px'
    , left: '500px'
});
$('img').click(function () {
    var randomNumber = Math.random();
    console.log(randomNumber);
        $('#output').html(function (i, val) {
            return val * 1 + 10
        });
    $(this).animate({
        top: '+=' + ((Math.random() * 500) - 400) + 'px'
        , left: '+=' + ((Math.random() * 500) - 400) + 'px'
    })
})

function explode() {
    alert("TIME UP!");
}
setTimeout(explode, 10000);
```

});

Is this solution just a css fix or does it need to be done in jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.
Don´t use "+=" in your animate.

```
$(this).animate({
    top: '+=' + ((Math.random() * 500) - 400) + 'px'
    , left: '+=' + ((Math.random() * 500) - 400) + 'px'
})
```

2.
To contain it in the viewport consider the use of
     `window.innerHeight` 
and
     `window.innerWidth`

3.
To contain it in a div you need to know the width and heigth of the div and consider that into your calculations (e.g. multiply the max with/height with a random number between 0 to 1 and subtract the image size from it)

Example to contain an image into the viewport

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
            integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<img style="background: black; width: 15px; height: 15px; position: relative"></img>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('img').click(function () {
            $(this).animate({
                top: (Math.random() * window.innerHeight - this.height) + 'px'
                , left: (Math.random() * window.innerWidth - this.width) + 'px'
            })
        })
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can easily adapt this to contain your image in your div.

Comment: Thank you very much, going to try this out.